# DES implementation

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, des

I'm trying to programm the Data Encyption Standard on my own and I'm struggling to Programm the SBoxes. I know there is already a module to encrypt and decrypt with the DES but my teacher asked to programm it myself, so here is what i have:

```
import random
from re import findall

class DES:
    def __init__(self):
        self. Eingabe=""
        self.Schluessel=""
        self.NachrichtBinaer=""
        self.Bitslinks=""
        self.Bitsrechts=""
        self.Teil1=""
        self.Teil2=""
        self.Subkey=""
        self.pcschluessel=""
        self.subkeyliste=[]
        self.initialpermutation=""
        self.liste1=[]
        self.Bits48=""
        self.ausgabesbox=[]
        self.liste2=[]


    def EingabeNachricht(self):
        self.Eingabe=input("Geben Sie ein Wort ein:")
        print ("Eingegebenes Wort: ",self.Eingabe)

    def Bitumwandlung(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.Eingabe)):
            self.NachrichtBinaer=self.NachrichtBinaer+bin(ord(self.Eingabe[i]))
            self.NachrichtBinaer=self.NachrichtBinaer.replace("b","")
        if len(self.NachrichtBinaer)<64:
            self.NachrichtBinaer=self.NachrichtBinaer.rjust(64,"0")
            self.NachrichtBinaer="0000000100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111"
        print ("Nachricht in Binaer: ",self.NachrichtBinaer)

    def Teilen(self):
        self.Bitslinks=self.initialpermutation[:int(len(self.initialpermutation)/2)]
        self.Bitsrechts=self.initialpermutation[int(len(self.initialpermutation)/2):]
        print ("Teil links: ",self.Bitslinks)
        print ("Teil rechts: ",self.Bitsrechts)

    def SchluesselGenerieren(self):
        #self.Schluessel= getrandbits(64)
        self.Schluessel="0001001100110100010101110111100110011011101111001101111111110001"

    def ippermutation(self):
        ip = [57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9,1,
        59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3,
        61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5,
        63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7,
        56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8,  0,
        58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2,
        60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4,
        62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6
        ]
        for i in ip:
            self.initialpermutation=self.initialpermutation+self.NachrichtBinaer[i]
        print ("Erste Permutation: ",self.initialpermutation)



    def Expandieren(self):

        ExpandierenTabelle = [
        31,0,1,2,3,4,
        3,4,5,6,7,8,
        7,8,9,10,11,12,
        11,12,13,14,15,16,
        15,16,17,18,19,20,
        9,20,21,22,23,24,
        3,24,25,26,27,28,
        27,28,29,30,31,0]

        for Elemente in ExpandierenTabelle:
            self.Bits48 = self.Bits48 + self.Bitsrechts[Elemente]
        print ("expandiert: ",self.Bits48)

    def XOR(self,wert1,wert2):
        antwort=wert1^wert2
        return antwort

    def SBox(self):
        self.sbox=[
        [[14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7],
         [0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8],
         [4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0],
         [15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 11, 3, 14, 10, 0, 6, 13]],

        # S2
        [[15, 1, 8, 14, 6, 11, 3, 4, 9, 7, 2, 13, 12, 0, 5, 10],
         [3, 13, 4, 7, 15, 2, 8, 14, 12, 0, 1, 10, 6, 9, 11, 5],
         [0, 14, 7, 11, 10, 4, 13, 1, 5, 8, 12, 6, 9, 3, 2, 15],
         [13, 8, 10, 1, 3, 15, 4, 2, 11, 6, 7, 12, 0, 5, 14, 9]],

        # S3
        [[10, 0, 9, 14, 6, 3, 15, 5, 1, 13, 12, 7, 11, 4, 2, 8],
         [13, 7, 0, 9, 3, 4, 6, 10, 2, 8, 5, 14, 12, 11, 15, 1],
         [13, 6, 4, 9, 8, 15, 3, 0, 11, 1, 2, 12, 5, 10, 14, 7],
         [1, 10, 13, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 15, 14, 3, 11, 5, 2, 12]],

        # S4
        [[7, 13, 14, 3, 0, 6, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8, 5, 11, 12, 4, 15],
         [13, 8, 11, 5, 6, 15, 0, 3, 4, 7, 2, 12, 1, 10, 14, 9],
         [10, 6, 9, 0, 12, 11, 7, 13, 15, 1, 3, 14, 5, 2, 8, 4],
         [3, 15, 0, 6, 10, 1, 13, 8, 9, 4, 5, 11, 12, 7, 2, 14]],

        # S5
        [[2, 12, 4, 1, 7, 10, 11, 6, 8, 5, 3, 15, 13, 0, 14, 9],
         [14, 11, 2, 12, 4, 7, 13, 1, 5, 0, 15, 10, 3, 9, 8, 6],
         [4, 2, 1, 11, 10, 13, 7, 8, 15, 9, 12, 5, 6, 3, 0, 14],
         [11, 8, 12, 7, 1, 14, 2, 13, 6, 15, 0, 9, 10, 4, 5, 3]],

        # S6
        [[12, 1, 10, 15, 9, 2, 6, 8, 0, 13, 3, 4, 14, 7, 5, 11],
         [10, 15, 4, 2, 7, 12, 9, 5, 6, 1, 13, 14, 0, 11, 3, 8],
         [9, 14, 15, 5, 2, 8, 12, 3, 7, 0, 4, 10, 1, 13, 11, 6],
         [4, 3, 2, 12, 9, 5, 15, 10, 11, 14, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 13]],

        # S7
        [[4, 11, 2, 14, 15, 0, 8, 13, 3, 12, 9, 7, 5, 10, 6, 1],
         [13, 0, 11, 7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 14, 3, 5, 12, 2, 15, 8, 6],
         [1, 4, 11, 13, 12, 3, 7, 14, 10, 15, 6, 8, 0, 5, 9, 2],
         [6, 11, 13, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 9, 5, 0, 15, 14, 2, 3, 12]],

        # S8
        [[13, 2, 8, 4, 6, 15, 11, 1, 10, 9, 3, 14, 5, 0, 12, 7],
         [1, 15, 13, 8, 10, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 6, 11, 0, 14, 9, 2],
         [7, 11, 4, 1, 9, 12, 14, 2, 0, 6, 10, 13, 15, 3, 5, 8],
         [2, 1, 14, 7, 4, 10, 8, 13, 15, 12, 9, 0, 3, 5, 6, 11]]
        ]

        for z in range(len(self.sbox)):
            for y in range(len(self.sbox[z])):
                for x in range(len(self.sbox[z][y])):
                    ausserebits=self.liste2[x][z][0]+self.liste2[x][z][-1]
                    innerebits=self.liste2[x][z][1:5]
                    print ("innere: ",innerebits)
                    print ("aussere: ",ausserebits)



    def pc1undteilen(self):
        pc1 = [56,48,40,32,24,16,8,
            0,57,49,41,33,25,17,
            9,1,58,50,42,34,26,
            18,19,2,59,51,43,35,
            62,54,46,38,30,22,14,
            6,61,53,45,37,29,21,
            13,5,60,52,44,36,28,
            20,2,4,27,19,11,3]

        #Subkey = ""

        for j in pc1:
            self.Subkey = self.Subkey+self.Schluessel[j]

        self.Teil1=self.Subkey[:int(len(self.Subkey)/2)]
        self.Teil2=self.Subkey[int(len(self.Subkey)/2):]
        print("Schluessel64 :",self.Subkey)
        print("SchluesselTeil1 :",self.Teil1)
        print("SchluesselTeil2 :",self.Teil2)

    def rotationundpc2(self):
        pc2 = [
        13, 16, 10, 23,  0,  4,
         2, 27, 14,  5, 20,  9,
        22, 18, 11,  3, 25,  7,
        15,  6, 26, 19, 12,  1,
        40, 51, 30, 36, 46, 54,
        29, 39, 50, 44, 32, 47,
        43, 48, 38, 55, 33, 52,
        45, 41, 49, 35, 28, 31]

        rotation = [
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]


        k=0
        #schluesselliste

        self.Teil1=list(self.Teil1)
        self.Teil2=list(self.Teil2)
        while k<16:
            #rotation
            u=0
            while u < rotation[k]:
                self.Teil1.append(self.Teil1[0])
                del self.Teil1[0]

                self.Teil2.append(self.Teil2[0])
                del self.Teil2[0]

                self.Teil1="".join(self.Teil1)
                self.Teil2="".join(self.Teil2)
                self.subschluessel=self.Teil1+self.Teil2
                print("Teil1: ",self.Teil1)
                print("Teil2: ",self.Teil2)
                print ("Subschluessel: ",self.subschluessel)
                self.Teil1=list(self.Teil1)
                self.Teil2=list(self.Teil2)
                u+=1

            #pc2 und erstellung der 16 subkeys
            for index2 in pc2:
                self.subkeyliste.append(self.subschluessel[index2])
            k+=1
        while len(self.subkeyliste)>0:
            self.liste1.append("".join(self.subkeyliste[0:48]))
            del self.subkeyliste[0:48]
        print ("Subkeyliste: ",self.liste1)

    def sechsbitunterteilung(self):
        for l in range(0,16):
            self.liste2.append(findall("......",listenachxor[l]))
        print ("liste2: ",self.liste2)

#objekt der klasse DES wird erstellt
listenachxor=[]
Krypto=DES()

#Schluesselgenerieren
Krypto.SchluesselGenerieren()
Krypto.pc1undteilen()
Krypto.rotationundpc2()

Krypto.EingabeNachricht()
Krypto.Bitumwandlung()
Krypto.ippermutation()
Krypto.Teilen()
Krypto.Expandieren()
for p in range(0,16):
    listenachxor.append(bin(Krypto.XOR(int(Krypto.liste1[p],2),int(Krypto.Bits48,2))))
    listenachxor[p]=listenachxor[p].replace("b","")
print ("listenachxor: ",listenachxor)
Krypto.sechsbitunterteilung()
Krypto.SBox()
```

By the way the problem is on this part of the programm, the rest just works fine:

```
    for z in range(len(self.sbox)):
        for y in range(len(self.sbox[z])):
            for x in range(len(self.sbox[z][y])):
                ausserebits=self.liste2[x][z][0]+self.liste2[x][z][-1]
                innerebits=self.liste2[x][z][1:5]
                print ("innere: ",innerebits)
                print ("aussere: ",ausserebits)
```

Comment: maybe compare to https://github.com/toddw-as/pyDes/blob/master/pyDes.py#L319

Comment: Already seen this implementation, but I'm not good enough to understand how it works exactly, it uses alot of functions I've never learned.

Comment: Should be correct now :)

Comment: Yes indeed good job, I couldn't get them matched! :) Now when running the script, on that same line I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`. Is this part of the problem?

Comment: That's the problem :D

Comment: @BastienLejoly Saying that you have a problem doesn't mean much. You should describe what the problem is. It seems that downshift hinted at what your problem might be. Please add your own proper description to your question.

Comment: @BastienLejoly, I'm not familiar with the DES algorithm implementation per-se, but if you can explain what needs to be done in that nested `for`-loop, we could probably figure out a solution

Comment: I'll try to explain it but my english isn't the best. self.liste2 equals a list containing 8 strings of length 6 containing bits, for example: "010011". and each of those strings goes into the corresponding SBox, first string into the first SBox and so on. What the Sbox does is, it takes the two outer bits of those strings and those two bits become the index of the row of the SBox in this case its's 01(binary)=1(decimal) and for the column you take the 4 inner bits to get the index of the column, in this case 1001(binary)=9(decimal).

Comment: When you have the index of the column and row you just replace the "010011" by the number in the SBox.

Comment: @BastienLejoly very good explanation, thanks! I'm not sure how your code does all of that, but if we can break that one line down into its smaller smaller pieces, check that it gets the correct data, and work on indexing the lists properly it should work.

Comment: for z in range(len(self.sbox)):
            for y in range(len(self.sbox[z])):
                for x in range(len(self.sbox[z][y])):
                    ausserebits=self.liste2[x][z][0]+self.liste2[x][z][-1]
                    innerebits=self.liste2[x][z][1:5]

I've changed my ode to this but it does work only halfway.

Comment: Cool, we can work with that, would you mind updating the code in your question with that change? Then we can narrow down why it's not working

Comment: I wish I had better understanding of what the desired output should look like. Just a guess, should the assignments be something like `ausserebits = self.liste2[x][0] + self.liste2[x][-1]` and `innerebits = self.liste2[x][1:5]`?